# Want to add class to elements with specific text else add another class

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this on my website:

```html
<p class="class_1">
    <a>text1</a>
    <a>text2</a>
    <a>text3</a>
</p>
```

I want to add class to each "a" elements in order to have something like this:

```html
<p class="class_1">
    <a class="class_3">text1</a>
    <a class="class_2">text2</a>
    <a class="class_3">text3</a>
</p>
```

Add a class_2 to elements which contains text2 or text6, and add class_3 to all the others.

I wrote some jquery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".class_1 a").each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(":contains('text2'), :contains('text6')")) {
      jQuery(this).addClass("class_2");
    };
    else {
      jQuery(this).addClass("class_3");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="class_1">
  <a>text1</a>
  <a>text2</a>
  <a>text3</a>
</p>
```

And there must be something wrong with my else (as it works without it to add the class_2) :D

Note that I'm not a dev at all (just know some basics), be kind ;)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check }; else {

Comment: Remove the `;` before `else`. Voting to close as a typo. For reference, you should always check the console for errors when JS code doesn't work as you expect. You can see the exact error if you run the snippet I edited in to your question.

Comment: Glad it helped. To open the console in most browsers it's the F12 key

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works like a charm now. I found the console but it was really explicit for me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else" ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply loop over all the `a` elements and add the class accordingly to your conditions:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text === 'text2' || text === 'text6'){
       $(this).addClass('class_2');
    } else {
       $(this).addClass('class_3');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.class_2{
  color: green;
}

.class_3{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="class_1">
    <a>text1</a>
    <a>text2</a>
    <a>text3</a>
    <a>text4</a>
    <a>text5</a>
    <a>text6</a>
</p>
```

Comment: `text() === 'xyz'` is not the same logic as `:contains`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the html seems to have only 'xyz' in anchor tag

Comment: You can't rely on the simplified code that someone edits in to the question being an accurate representation. You're also restricting the use case of the logic.